# Parsing Nested JSON array to an Array using GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

I need to parse the following Json

```
[
    "foo",
    [
        "foot mercato",
        "football",
        "foot center",
        "foorzik",
        "footao"
    ]
]
```

in java using **Gson**.

Im really interested in values in the Array:
so far I have tried:

```
String jsonStr = "[" + "\"foo\"," + " [" + "  \"foot mercato\"," + "  \"football\"," + "  \"foot center\"," +
                "  \"foorzik\"," + "  \"footao\"" + " ]" + "]";

JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonArray array = parser.parse(jsonStr).getAsJsonArray();
```

any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you get your array, you can iterate through all the elements of it.

```
for(JsonElement e : array) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

which will output

```
"foo"
["foot mercato","football","foot center","foorzik","footao"]
```

If you only want the values in the nested array, you can do:

```
JsonArray nestedArray = parser.parse(jsonStr).getAsJsonArray().get(1).getAsJsonArray();
for(JsonElement e : nestedArray) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

which will output

```
"foot mercato"
"football"
"foot center"
"foorzik"
"footao"
```

Answer (score 1):

This may help:

```
String jsonStr = "[" + "\"foo\"," + " [" + "  \"foot mercato\"," + "  \"football\"," + "  \"foot center\","
                + "  \"foorzik\"," + "  \"footao\"" + " ]" + "]";

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        ArrayList<Object> dest = new ArrayList<Object>();
        dest = gson.fromJson(jsonStr, dest.getClass());

        for (Object e : dest) {
            System.out.println("T:" + e.getClass().getCanonicalName());
            if (e instanceof String) {
                System.out.println(e);
            } else if (e instanceof ArrayList) {
                for (String ele : (ArrayList<String>) e) {
                    System.out.println(ele);
                }
            }
        }
```

Will generate:

T:java.lang.String

foo

T:java.util.ArrayList

foot mercato

football

foot center

foorzik

footao